# Docker container RestartCount not incrementing

Tags: docker, dockerpy

#### Test

```
def test_can_pop_new_container(self):
    config = {
        'ip': '10.49.0.2',
        'subnet': '10.49.0.0/16',
        'gateway': '10.49.0.202',
        'vlan': 102,
        'hostname': 'test-container',
    }
    container = container_services.pop_new_container(config, self.docker_api)

    inspection = self.docker_api.inspect_container(container.get('Id'))
    print('before', inspection.get('RestartCount'), inspection.get('StartedAt'))
    container_services.restart(container, self.docker_api)
    new_inspection = self.docker_api.inspect_container(container.get('Id'))
    print('after', new_inspection.get('RestartCount'), new_inspection.get('StartedAt'))
```

#### Code

```
def restart(container, docker_client):
    return docker_client.restart(container.get('Id'))
```

#### Output

From the test I get

```
before 0 None
after 0 None
```

From `docker ps` that confirm the container restarted.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
86f16438ffdd        docker.akema.fr:5000/coaxis/coaxisopt_daemon:latest   "/usr/bin/supervis..."   28 seconds ago      Up 17 seconds                           confident_dijkstra
```

#### Question

Why is `RestartCount` still at `0` then? Am I using the wrong field?

Comment: I have no facts to back this up, but my personal opinion is that a manual_restart != docker_initiated_restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already indicated in the comment, the field `RestartCount` is used in the context of [Restart Policies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart) to keep track of restart attempts in case of failures.

It will not be incremented in case of user-initiated restarts.

You can look at [docker events](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/) to keep track on normal container restarts. This is also available for [dockerpy](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.3/api/#events).